# Abort php script execution when jquery ajax is aborted

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, apache

I'm looking to stop the execution of a PHP script when the jQuery `$.post` is aborted by `abort()`. Basically whenever a user changes any input field the `$.post` should hit the `test.php`. If a second input is changed before the first request returns, the `$.post` is aborted and a new one is sent. I want PHP to stop execution when this happens.

According to [PHP manual on connection handlnig](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) :

> connection_status() return ABORTED state ONLY if the client disconnects gracefully (with STOP button). In this case the browser send the RST TCP packet that notify PHP the connection is closed.

Is there anyway to send the `RST TCP` when using `xhr.abort()`?

To make sure I've tested this in the `test.php` file. Theoretically if the script is stopped the files should have different sizes and number of lines in them. But they're all the same. So the script is not aborting.

jQuery main file:

```
var xhr = false;
$('input').on('change', function(){
    if(xhr){
        xhr.abort();
    }

    xhr = $.post('/test.php', this.value, function(b64){
        xhr = false;
    });
});
```

PHP test.php

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/test1.log', "1\r\n",  FILE_APPEND);
sleep(1);
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/test2.log', "1\r\n",  FILE_APPEND);
sleep(1);
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/test3.log', "1\r\n",  FILE_APPEND);
sleep(1);
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/test4.log', "1\r\n",  FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @poletaew [According to the php docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php) "The default behaviour is however for your script to be aborted when the remote client disconnects." Though i've had a difficult time validating this is practice.

Comment: this is a lie... either jquery is not signaling to the server that the user aborted or php is ignoring it completely.

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

> Notes
>
> PHP will not detect that the user has aborted the connection until an attempt is made to send information to the client. Simply using an echo statement does not guarantee that information is sent, see [flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php).

And also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php

Maybe a little re-write would help:

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  if(connection_aborted()) {
    echo "\r\n\r\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    exit;
  }
  file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/test' . ($i+1) . '.log', "1\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Tried your re-write. Still didn't work. All files are the same size. Doesn't work going to the address directly in the browser and pressing the stop button either.